# Access Arguments Input via Artisan Console Command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-artisan

I want to run my command like this

```
php artisan update:code --code=123
```

I want to get the code from first argument - I can't seems to find a way to do it on Laravel site.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class updateCode extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'update:code {code}';


    protected $description = 'Update Code ... ';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        $code         = $this->option('code');
        $this->info($code);
        $user         = User::where('type','Admin')->first();
        $user->code   = bcrypt($code);
        $user->active = 1;
        $user->save();

        $this->info($user);

    }
}
```

I kept getting

> The "--code" option does not exist.

Do I need to defind my option too ?

How can I just quickly access the first argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{code}` is for [arguments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#arguments). For [options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#options) it is `{--code}` or `{--code=}`:

```
// option as switch:
protected $signature = 'update:code {--code}';
// option with value:
protected $signature = 'update:code {--code=}';
```

Comment: I did `php artisan update:code --code=123` and got `The "--code" option does not accept a value.`

Comment: __Read the manual further please__. Meanwhile I update the answer with `{--code=}` example.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
php artisan update:code 123
```

Comment: How do we access 123 in the code ? $1 ? Can you show that part ?